# Moving a site (drupal8) to MAMP, autoload.php error

Tags: php, http, mamp, drupal-8

Somebody send me a site to work on so I setup my MAMP webserver, extracted the drupal8 files into the htdocs folder, I setup the database in phpMyAdmin and run the MAMP servers.

When I try to reach localhost I get a `HTTP ERROR 500`, of-course I check the logs for errors and find this:

> [02-Aug-2017 16:14:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(C:\MAMP\htdocs/../vendor/autoload.php): 
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\MAMP\htdocs\autoload.php on line 17
>
> [02-Aug-2017 16:14:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\MAMP\htdocs/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\MAMP\htdocs\autoload.php on line 17

I thought this had something to do with composer so I reinstalled it and ran cmd

```
composer install
```

In installed some files + generated some autoload files which is what i thought was going to solve my problem, but i still get the same error and i feel like im missing something really obvious. Ive been stuck for so long on a small problem.

Hope someone has an answer for me!

Comment: First of all look at that path above.  Where is `vendor/autoload.php`?  Can you correct the path?

Comment: That was actually it wow, I cant believe i didnt see that it was a pathing error, im garbage. Sorry for wasting people's time

Answer (score 1):

## **SOLVED**

It was a pathing error in the autoload.php file

return require **DIR** . '../vendor/autoload.php';

changed to:

return require **DIR** . '/vendor/autoload.php';